# Condition: Non-Symmetric Matrix with real eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a necessary condition for a non-symmetric real matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to have all its eigenvalues real and positive?

Comment: Positive Trace?

Comment: I would like to introduce this condition into a generalized eigenvalue problem, the eigenvalues with such a condition could be complex right?

Answer (score 1):

For a matrix $A$, all of its eigenvalus are real iff  the 
$n\times n$ matrix $(\textrm{Tr} (A^{i+j})\,)_{ i,j=0}^{n-1}$ is positive semi-definite.

For complex numbers $\alpha_1$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_n$, we have: all of the numbers $\alpha_k$ are real if and only if the symmetric matrix $(\sum \alpha_k^{i+j})_{i,j=0}^{n-1}$ is real and positive semi-definite, check for eg [An Introduction to Algebraic Geometry](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/SAG.pdf) by Michel Coste.

Now, if you already know that all of the eigenvalue of $A$ are real, they will be $\ge 0$ if and only the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has coefficients of alternating signs.